# How do I put textarea data into an SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, textarea, ado

(This is classic ASP)
I'm sure this is just a case of escaping the text, but I haven't found anything yet.
I have a textarea that may contain all sorts of characters and I need to UPDATE the record with whatever is in that textarea, but I'm getting an error that breaks my SQL query, which I'm positive is related to the content of the textarea.

So I have this so far as my SQL query:

```
"UPDATE document SET displayheading='" & _
    stripillegal(request("txt_displayheading")) & _
    "', displayorder=" & displayorder & _
    ", shortdescription='" & stripillegal(request("txt_shortdescription")) & _
    "', document_note='" & request("document_note") ...blah blah blah
```

So I'm wondering how do I contain the textarea so that I can update the record without ruining the query?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: BTW: You have a SQL Injection vulnerability in this code.

Comment: Consider using prepared SQL statements or stored procs with parameters then using data access middelware (e.g. ADO) to handle passing parameter values and you will get 'stripillegal', 'FormatDateText', etc functionality for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to avoid dynamic SQL and address the SQL injection potential.  It uses a parameterized query.  Here's a SQL solution:

```
    DECLARE @DisplayHeading varchar(100)
    DECLARE @DisplayOrder int
    DECLARE @ShortDescription varchar(100)
    DECLARE @DocumentNote varchar(100)

    DECLARE @command nvarchar(500)
    DECLARE @params nvarchar(500)

    SET @command = N'UPDATE document
        SET displayheading=@DisplayHeading
        , displayorder=@DisplayOrder
        , shortdescription=@ShortDescription
        , document_note=@DocumentNote
        --...blah blah blah'

    SET @params = N'@DisplayHeading varchar(100), @DisplayOrder int, 
             @ShortDescription varchar(100), @DocumentNote varchar(100)'

-- Assign values to user variables.

EXEC sp_executesql @command, @params, @DisplayHeading,
     @DisplayOrder, @ShortDescription, @DocumentNote
```

And here's what you can try with ADO:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE document " & _
         "SET displayheading=@DisplayHeading, displayorder=@DisplayOrder, " & _
         "shortdescription=@ShortDescription, document_note=@DocumentNote " & _
         "--...blah blah blah"

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DisplayHeading", DisplayHeading))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DisplayOrder", DisplayOrder))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ShortDescription", ShortDescription))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DocumentNote", DocumentNote))
```

Answer (score 1):

The query will break if there is character like `'`, you need to replace them first:

```
newStr = Replace("'", "''", request("txt_displayheading"))
```

And in your query use the `newStr` variable instead of `request("txt_displayheading"`

Comment: Need an extra ) at the end there

Comment: You don't want to straight up remove them.  Imagine if stackoverflow did that, the word "don't" in this comment would go into the database as "dont".  You just want to replace a single quote with two single quotes.

Comment: do not remove the `'` as they might be wanted .. change them to `''` and they get saved correctly..

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone, @jMerliN, @Gaby: Thanks guys updated, no coffie today i guess :(